# printing data in a table format from mysql using php vertically

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, this seems to be difficult to explain but I'm on my limit now. Been there, done that but I can't get this to work. So here it is;

I have a table named `passengers` that has these following data:

[image]

I'm trying to select the following data in this table format:

[image]

using this code:

```
<?php
require("aacfs.php");
$ac=mysql_query("select distinct fquo_id as 'fquo_id' from passengers where reservno = '0000188'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table><tr>";
while($bd=mysql_fetch_array($ac))
{
    $eg=$bd['fquo_id'];
    $w=mysql_query("select * from passengers where fquo_id = '$eg'") or die(mysql_error());
    $no=1;
    while($x=mysql_fetch_array($w))
    {
        $y=$x['pass_name'];

        echo "<tr><td colspan=2>$no. <input type=text name='pass1_".$no."' value='$y'></td><td>$no. <input type=text name='pass2_".$no."' value='$y'></td></tr>";
        $no++;
    }
}

echo"</tr></table>";

?>
```

But it looks something like this:

[image]

I know I'm doing something wrong but believe me I've been modifying this for a while and still can't make it the way I want it to. This is the closest I can get to my desired output. How can I properly print table vertically? I know a code like `SELECT * FROM tbl \G` but it doesn't work in PHP. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require("aacfs.php");
$ac         =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM passengers WHERE reservno = '0000188' ORDER BY fquo_id, pass_id") or die(mysql_error());
$temp_array = array();
while($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($ac)){
    $temp_array[$row['fquo_id']][] = $row;
}

$td_count   = count($temp_array);
$tr_count   = 1;
$fquo_id    = array();

foreach($temp_array as $key=>$val){
  if($tr_count < count($val)){$tr_count = count($val);}
  $fquo_id[]= $key;
}
$tr_count   = 8; // if you want to display 8 rows;
echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i<$tr_count; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    $no  = $i+1;
    for($j=0; $j<$td_count; $j++){
        echo "<td>";
        if(array_key_exists($i,$temp_array[$fquo_id[$j]])){
            echo $no.". <input type=text name='pass1_".$no."' value='".$temp_array[$fquo_id[$j]][$i]['pass_name']."'>";
        }
        else{
            echo $no.". <input type=text name='pass1_".$no."' value=''>";
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that, It is done with a single query you dont want two queries :D

Comment: That worked! Thanks! :) How can I output by default 8 textboxes per existing distinct fquo_id and just leave them blank if they don't have any values? Example (based on your result): (1st column): 1. prasanth, 2. test, 3. *blank textbox .... 8. *blank textbox || (2nd column) 1. prasanth, 2. test, 3. bendra, 4. *blank textbox ... 8. *blank textbox. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: There variable `$tr_count` which determines your rows, so manually make it 8, ie `$tr_count= 8;`, but what if more than 8 entries are there in database for one fquo_id

Comment: What if I want to save the value of textboxes through `$_POST`? I tried getting `$_POST['pass1_1']`'s value but it prints nothing. What are the textboxes' respective names? Thanks.

Comment: you make it array name='pass1[".$no."]', then try print_r(pass1);

Comment: I've set the, `name='pass1[".$no."]'`. Did you mean `print_r($_POST['pass11']);`? I tried, but it displays nothing.

Comment: ohhh...sorry it is `print_r($_POST['pass1']);`

Comment: OR better you use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";` you can see all the values that are posting.

Comment: `Array ( [1] => prasanth [2] => test [3] => bendra [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => ) `. So how can I get the 1st column's textbox value?

Comment: May i know what exactly you are looking for ??? update values in database ?? in that case i can give you a better solution

Comment: Update and inserting new values. As I have asked you previously to output 8 textboxes with the values from the database (if it has). Then, depending on the user if he wants to update the existing data and add some more. I hope my explanation was clear. Thanks a lot for helping me! :)

Comment: so change your name of the text boxes to `name='pass1[".$pass_id."]'`, and in php you foreach the $_POST['pass1'], you will get key as pass_id and values as it s value, so check for key with pass_id in DB if it exists update it or insert a new value.

Comment: And the `$pass_id` will hold what value?

Comment: pass_id value in your DB which is unique for a data. I guess you may have to do little more as you need the value of fquo_id for each data make you text name a multi demsional array with `['fquo_id']['pass_id']` this will solve your issue. :D

Comment: I changed the name and tried to output it, `print_r($_POST['pass1'.$pass_id]);` But it still outputs the array before. I can't still get the name of the textboxes on the 1st column. :(

Comment: `print_r($_POST['pass1']);` use this

Comment: dont give dynamic name, make it array with same name with [$pass_id]

Comment: Still the same array as before.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting your point. What do you mean by same name with [$pass_id]?

Comment: It's working. I just forgot to click the submit button. Sorry. How am I going to update the database using the value of this array, `$_POST['pass1']`? I'm not that good with handling array so I'm at lost here.

Comment: Only the outputting of the array of the both columns. :) But I'm still at lost at how to update using this variable, `$_POST['pass1']`, since it holds an array value. How am I suppose to update using array?

Comment: foreach($_POST['pass1'] as $key=>$val){//$key will be pass_id and //$val will be value of text box now you can update}

Comment: That was amazing! Thanks a lot for all your help! I really appreciate it! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I understood properly what you want, the follwoing should work

```
<?php
...
    $no=1;
    while($x1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($w))
    {
        $y1 = $x1['pass_name'];
        $y2 = "";
        if($x2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($w))
           $y2 = $x2['pass_name'];            

        echo "<tr><td colspan=2>$no. <input type=text name='pass1_" . $no . "' value='" . $y1 . "'></td><td>$no. <input type=text name='pass2_" . $no . "' value='" . $y2 . "'></td></tr>";
        $no++;
    }
...

?>
```

Comment: the variable `$x1` holds what query?

Comment: I simply replaced your `$x` with `$x1`, because I needed a `$x2`. Both `$x1` and `$x2` do not hold a query, but an associative array that is one row of the query result.

Comment: Yeah got it. But it prints: (1st row) 1. *blank || 1. steve kazee (nd row) 1. *blank || 1. bella cullen

Comment: I left one `$x` by mistake, now fixed, and you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fext_array`

Comment: prints: (1st row) 1. christina perri || 1. steve kazee (2nd row) 1. edward cullen || 1. bella cullen

Comment: @xjshiya: I thought it was what you wanted, I evntually misunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

See if this [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/06s-ed9) can help you, if then, your code should be changed to:

```
<?php
require("aacfs.php");
$ac=mysql_query("select distinct fquo_id as 'fquo_id' from passengers where reservno = '0000188'") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table>";
while($bd=mysql_fetch_array($ac))
{
    $eg=$bd['fquo_id'];
    $w=mysql_query("select * from passengers where fquo_id = '$eg'") or die(mysql_error());

    $n = 2;
    $i = 0;
    while($x=mysql_fetch_array($w))
    {
       $i++;
       if($n % 2 == 0){
        echo  "<tr>";
       }
       $y=$x['pass_name'];

       echo "<td colspan=2>$no. <input type=text name='pass1_".$no."' value='$y'></td>";
       if($n % 2 == $n){
        echo  "</tr>";
       }
       $n++;
    }
}

echo"</table>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ac=mysql_query("select distinct fquo_id as 'fquo_id' from passengers where reservno ='0000188'") or die(mysql_error());
while($bd=mysql_fetch_array($ac))
{echo "<table>";
    $eg=$bd['fquo_id'];
    $w=mysql_query("select * from passengers where fquo_id = '$eg'") or die(mysql_error());
    $no=1;
    while($x=mysql_fetch_array($w))
    {
        $y=$x['pass_name'];

  echo "<tr><td>$no. <input type=text name='pass1_".$no."' value='$y'></td></tr>";
        $no++;
    }
</table>
}
```

try this.. :P

Comment: prints only 1 column.. 1. christina perri, 2. steve kazee, 1. edward cullen, 2. bella cullen..